# How to generate uniform random numbers using random.random()

Tags: python-3.x, random

I want to generate uniform random number in a range '***n***' by using **random.random()** in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Integers:

`int(random.uniform(0, 1) * n)` will be 0 to n - 1

`int(random.uniform(0, 1) * n) + 1` will be 1 to n

`int(random.uniform(0, 1) * (n + 1))` will be 0 to n

For Floats:

`random.uniform(0, n)` will be 0 to n

`random.uniform(1, n)` will be 1 to n

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: For integers, use `random.randrange` in preference to `random.uniform`.